# Running Spring Security and Struts JUnit tests in tandem

Tags: java, spring, struts2, junit, spring-security

Currently, in my web application, I'm trying to run a series of unit tests for Struts 2.0.6 and Spring 3.  In doing so, I've come across an issue where I have both tests call on the context configuration paths separately in their own respective tests and throw exceptions saying that certain beans have already been wired.

For my Struts unit test, I've extended the BaseStrutsTestCase, found here:
http://depressedprogrammer.wordpress.com/2007/06/18/unit-testing-struts-2-actions-spring-junit

I've configured the context configuration path as follows for the struts action test:

```
private static final String CONFIG_LOCATIONS = "classpath:applicationContext-test.xml";
```

Then I've gone ahead and created a separate Spring JUnit test for the login functionality for Spring Security:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@WebAppConfiguration
@ContextConfiguration({"classpath:applicationContext-test.xml"})
public class UserAuthenticationTest {

    @Autowired
    protected UserManagementService userManagementService;

    @Test
    public void testUserSuccess() {

        ArrayList<GrantedAuthority> grantedAuthorities = 
            new ArrayList<GrantedAuthority>();

        ConsoleUser consoleUser = 
            userManagementService.getConsoleUser("user@test.com","password");

       if (consoleUser == null){
            Assert.assertTrue(consoleUser == null);
       } else {
            for (ConsoleRole role : consoleUser.getRoles()){
                StringBuilder permissions = new StringBuilder();
                    for (ConsolePermission permission : role.getPermissions()){
                        grantedAuthorities.add(new GrantedAuthorityImpl(permission.getPermissionType().toString()));
                        permissions.append(permission.getPermissionType().toString() + " ");
                    }
            }

            Authentication authentication = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(consoleUser.getEmail(), consoleUser.getPassword(), grantedAuthorities);

            SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authentication);
            Assert.assertTrue(true);
        }

    }
}
```

So I ran my unit test suite (1 struts action and 1 Spring test), and the following exception gets thrown in my logs:

```
2974 [main] ERROR org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader  - Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'messageSource' defined in class path resource [spring-messagesource-config.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'messageBundleLocation' while setting bean property 'basename'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'messageBundleLocation' defined in class path resource [spring-messagesource-config.xml]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'com.googlecode.ehcache.annotations.config.internalEhCacheCachingAdvisor': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'com.googlecode.ehcache.annotations.impl.CacheStaticMethodMatcherPointcut#0' while setting bean property 'pointcut'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'com.googlecode.ehcache.annotations.impl.CacheStaticMethodMatcherPointcut#0': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'com.googlecode.ehcache.annotations.impl.CacheAttributeSourceImpl#0' while setting bean property 'cacheAttributeSource'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'com.googlecode.ehcache.annotations.impl.CacheAttributeSourceImpl#0': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'facadeCacheManager' while setting bean property 'cacheManager'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'facadeCacheManager' defined in class path resource [spring-cache-config-test.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is net.sf.ehcache.CacheException: Another CacheManager with same name 'API_CACHE_MANAGER' already exists in the same VM. Please provide unique names for each CacheManager in the config or do one of following:
1. Use one of the CacheManager.create() static factory methods to reuse same CacheManager with same name or create one if necessary
2. Shutdown the earlier cacheManager before creating new one with same name.
The source of the existing CacheManager is: InputStreamConfigurationSource [stream=sun.net.www.protocol.jar.JarURLConnection$JarURLInputStream@327df0b7]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:329)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:107)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1387)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1128)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:519)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:458)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:295)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:223)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:292)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:198)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.initMessageSource(AbstractApplicationContext.java:786)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:467)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:389)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:294)
    at BaseStrutsTestCase.setUp(BaseStrutsTestCase.java:80)
    at junit.framework.TestCase.runBare(TestCase.java:139)
    at junit.framework.TestResult$1.protect(TestResult.java:122)
    at junit.framework.TestResult.runProtected(TestResult.java:142)
    at junit.framework.TestResult.run(TestResult.java:125)
    at junit.framework.TestCase.run(TestCase.java:129)
    at junit.framework.TestSuite.runTest(TestSuite.java:255)
    at junit.framework.TestSuite.run(TestSuite.java:250)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.JUnit38ClassRunner.run(JUnit38ClassRunner.java:84)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4TestSet.execute(JUnit4TestSet.java:62)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.suite.AbstractDirectoryTestSuite.executeTestSet(AbstractDirectoryTestSuite.java:140)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.suite.AbstractDirectoryTestSuite.execute(AbstractDirectoryTestSuite.java:127)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.Surefire.run(Surefire.java:177)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.SurefireBooter.runSuitesInProcess(SurefireBooter.java:345)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.SurefireBooter.main(SurefireBooter.java:1009)
```

Is there a way to run these tests one after another, either by persisting the beans already created by my Spring unit tests or destroying the context configuration after the Spring unit test is done running and then having Struts use the context configuration within BaseStrutsTestCase?

Comment: The only way is to upgrade...

Comment: Do you mean to upgrade Struts 2 to Struts 3 or upgrade to a higher version of Struts 2?

Comment: I'd recommend you to format the code, so I was unable to read it horizontally, totally upset.

Comment: I've tried to reformat so that it's less horizontal scrolling.